# Can I install gtk on xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, frameworks, gtk

I've been doing PHP for a long time now and I'd like to make some desktop applications on my Mac. I've never used C before but I installed xcode and I could do some basic things with some terminal apps.

I'd like to make an application with a GUI. I don't know how to add libraries or frameworks in xcode though and I don't know how to install the GTK library/framework so I can start using it when I code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a popular GTK framework that works with Xcode GTK-OSX, at http://gtk-osx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm not sure how I can access GTK within xcode after I've installed that!